# Simple way to write Cumulative distribution function of $\alpha X + \beta$?

Tags: probability-theory, summation

Let $X$ be a discrete random variable with Cumulative Distribution Function $F$. What is the cumulative distribution function of the random variable $\alpha X + \beta$, where $\alpha, \beta$ are constants and $\alpha \ne 0$?

Let $Y = \alpha X + \beta$. We want to find the CDF for $Y$. Going completely by definition, I have 
$$\mathrm{P}(Y \le a) = \sum_{\large y\ \in Y:\ y\  \le\ a\ \ \ } \sum_{\large x\ \in X:\ \  \alpha x + \beta = y} \mathrm{P}(x) $$

for some $a \in Y$.   Now, because it can be proven that

$$\mathrm{E}[\alpha X + \beta] = \alpha\mathrm{E}[X] + \beta$$

Is there a way to apply this result, or one something similar, to simplify the expression I gave above for $\mathrm{P}(Y \le a)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write: $F_Y(y) = P(Y < y) = P(\alpha X + \beta < y)$ and turn this into an expression of the form $P(X < \;?)$.

Comment: something like this? $P(X\ \le \frac{y-\beta}{\alpha}) = F(\frac{y-\beta}{\alpha})$

Comment: Perfect.  Though since you're dealing with the cdf's for $X$ and $Y$, you might want to be explicit about it. :)

Comment: OK, more explicitly, for example, $P(Y \le y) = F_x(\frac{y-\beta}{\alpha})$

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that $\alpha$ is positive. Then $Y\le y$ if and only if $\alpha X+\beta\le y$ if and only if $\alpha X\le y-\beta$ if and only if $X\le \frac{y-\beta}{\alpha}$.

Thus if $\alpha \gt 0$, then 
$$F_Y(y)=F\left(\frac{y-\beta}{\alpha}\right).$$

If $\alpha\lt 0$, things are more complicated, for then $Y\le y$ if and only if $X\ge \frac{y-\beta}{\alpha}$.  And $\Pr(X\ge a)=1-\lim_{t\to a^-} F(t)$. It follows that
$$F_Y(y)=\lim_{t \to z^-} (1-F(t)),$$
where $z=\frac{y-\beta}{\alpha}$.

Comment: As extensive and helpful your answer is, one reason I decided to accept nomen's answer was that nomen helped me realize the solution first. I'm sure others will upvote your answer. But I emphasize I really appreciate your answer.

Comment: You are welcome. For the future, please note that the cumulative distribution of $X$ is the probability that $X\le x$. If the distribution of $X$ is continuous, that makes no difference, since $\Pr(X=x)=0$. But in other cases it does. And when $\alpha$ is negative, we have to be careful, for dividing by $\alpha$ reverses inequalities.

Comment: such as cases where the distribution of $X$ is discrete. To your observation on $\alpha$, I think it's interesting that the textbook allows us to assume $\alpha \ne 0$ but not $\alpha \gt 0$. And the question I posted is more or less the textbook problem **word-for-word**.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the stackexchange would let you unaccept my answer if you want.  I don't mind either way (I do like the points, but Andre gave a more complete answer)

Comment: @nomen: You gave the first answer. Just because I am more wordy and have a preoccupation with negative numbers seems to me no reason for acceptance to be changed.